# Notepad++: Remove Workspace

Tags: notepad++

How can I remove a workspace from Notepad++?

I have created some workspaces (out of curiosity).

Now I'd lie to remove/delete those empty ones.

(NPP: 6.9.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you switch from one workspace to another?

I have to use  the Workspace ->`Open Workspace` menu item  and select the file in witch the workspace was saved.
So I would say to get rid of the empty ones: you delete the files on the disk that correspond to empty workspaces.

Comment: I have just clicked 'Workspace' and the selected 'New Workspace' to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just clicked 'Workspace' and the selected 'New Workspace' to create a new one. So I created 3 workspaces. Which now does not work that easy (???!!)

One ws I used and two empty ones. When I now tried to remove the empry ones, this question arose as there is no 'Remove' option.

When I tried to double click the 'project-header' the window disconnecte and I could easily close it (the ws was still empty).

So I can consider it closed.